# Who were the physical models and the voice actors used for each party member in Dragon Age?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition, dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-2

Many of the party members had face models assigned to them in the design phase. I would like to know who the model each party member is based upon is in all three games and also the voice actor for each party member as well. Links would be helpful.

Comment: I could see this being debated as being too broad.. That said, I'm going to provide a list of party members. Hopefully users can edit the 'model actor' with appropriate links, as names can be confirmed. For completion sake, I'll list the few that would not have used human models, as they may have still had human voice actors.

Comment: Though broad, I thought this was an ok question. It is not vague and does have an answer.

Comment: Would you consider changing the question to "who are the associated actors" to include voice acting? Would make it easy for me to fill out this list, and eventually hope to have a more detailed list including physical models, which might in turn ease the opinion of this being too broad

Answer (score 2):

#### Dragon Age: Origins

- [Alistair](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Alistair) : [inspired by the characters](http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/47/index/440856?lf=8) [Xander Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xander_Harris) of Buffy the Vampire Slayer and [Mal Reynold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_Reynolds)s of FireFly, voiced by [Steve Valentine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Valentine#Video_games).
- [Dog](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Dog_(Origins)) : animal; No actor or voice actor.
- [Leliana](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Leliana) : Modeled by  [Alexandra Stein AKA "Alleykatze](http://vk.com/album-34908971_168170708)
- [Morrigan](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Morrigan) : Modeled by [Victoria Johnson](http://www.modelmayhem.com/1132240), voiced by [Claudia Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claudia_Black#Filmography).
- [Oghren](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Oghren) : Voiced by [Steve Blum](http://www.steveblumvoices.com/?page_id=1068)
- [Shale](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Shale) : Voiced by [Geraldine Blecker](http://www.geraldine-blecker.com/references.htm).
- [Sten](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Sten) : Voiced by [Mark Hildreth](http://mark-hildreth.com/)
- [Wynne](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Wynne) : Voiced by [Susan Boyd Joyce](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0101928/)
- [Zevran Arainai](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Zevran_Arainai) : Voiced by [Jon Curry](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0193087/)

#### Dragon Age II

- [Anders](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Anders) :
- [Aveline Vallen](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Aveline_Vallen) :
- [Bethany Hawke](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Bethany_Hawke) :
- [Carver Hawke](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Carver_Hawke) :
- [Fenris](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Fenris) :
- [Isabela](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Isabela) :
- [Merril](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Merrill) :
- [Sebastian Vael](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Sebastian_Vael) :
- [Varric Tethras](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Varric_Tethras) :
- [Tallis](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Tallis) :

#### Dragon Age: Inquisition

- [Blackwall](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Blackwall) :
- [Cassandra Pentaghast](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Cassandra_Pentaghast) :
- [Cole](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Cole) :
- [Dorian Pavus](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Dorian_Pavus) :
- [Iron Bull](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Bull) :
- [Sera](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Sera) :
- [Solas](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Solas) :
- [Varric Tethras](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Varric_Tethras) :
- [Vivienne](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Vivienne) :

Comment: Thanks, it's a start. Please fill in the name of the face model used for each character.

Comment: Some characters simply will not have face models, as the developer uses several 'models' for inspiration. Alistair appears to be a good example.

Comment: Good point, you could just write in "no model" or something if you have confirmation on that.

Comment: Leaving the extra information in. Still relevant, and it might be of more use to future readers. In the case of Alistair, there is no specific model. But the developer used the inspiration of other characters in its creation, so they would become 'partial models'... if that makes sense